# How to detect teleportation to a particular area in unity VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, vrtk

I need to call a function when teleported to a particular area. How can I achieve this using VRTK and unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VRTK_HeadsetCollision

> Script Usage: Place the `VRTK_HeadsetCollision` script on any active scene GameObject.

Other than that it's pretty much a plain [trigger collider](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers) workflow